# Cannot set property for tomcat

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, tomcat7, catalina

I need to set the next property to catalina.propeties file for proper application work:

```
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.STRICT_WHITESPACE=false
```

But when I start tomcat from eclipse it sets defaul settings to catalina.properties (overwrites) and removes the string.

Besides if I set "read only" to catalina.properties I cannot startup tomcat from eclipse.

Comment: Sorry, I had similar problem before where eclipse was overwriting my config files. I remember there was a checkbox saying "don't touch my files" but I don't remember where it is. :(
P.S the label of the checkbox wasn't that but I would have programmed that. :)

Comment: I can't find this checkbox but I'v solved the problem :) I believe :)

Answer (score 0):

I was modifying catalina.properties file in conf directory of the tomcat instalation. But I should modify catalina.properties in server project created in my workspace.